# airport -s -x returns truncated output

Tags: network, wifi, airport, plist, xml

I am the author of `wifi-wand`, a Ruby command line utility that can be used as a simple way to manage the Mac's WiFi (https://github.com/keithrbennett/wifiwand) without having to learn all the different underlying Mac OS commands and their options.

To get a list of network names, I used to use `airport -s` but found that it does not work because since the network names are right justified (left padded), there is no way to know if leading spaces are part of the name or just there for formatting. So I use `airport -s -x` to get the information displayed in (pseudo-)XML.

This almost always works, but I've noticed in several locations, if there is an HP printer network, the output terminates somewhere in that element. For example:

```
           <key>SSID_STR</key>
           <string>DIRECT-0E-HP OfficeJet 4650</string>
           <key>WPS_PROB_RESP_IE</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>IE_KEY_WPS_AP_SETUP_LOCKED</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>IE_KEY_WPS_CFG_METHODS</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>IE_KEY_WPS_DEV_NAME</key>
                    <string>DIRECT-0E-HP OfficeJet 4650</string>
                    <key>IE_KEY_WPS_DEV_NAME_DATA</key>
                    <data>
                    RElSRUNULTBFLUhQIE9mZmljZUpldCA0NjUw
                    </data>
                    <key>IE_KEY_WPS_MANUFACTURER</key>
                    <string>HP</string>
                    <key>IE_KEY_WPS_MODEL_NAME</key>
                    <string>OfficeJet 4650 series
```

Without the `-x` option, the output works, but, as I say, there is the space issue that prevents me from relying on it:

```
                        SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                NETGEAR25-5G a0:04:60:1a:5a:89 -67  153,-1  Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
 DIRECT-0E-HP OfficeJet 4650 ac:e2:d3:a9:d9:0f -90  6       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                      iPhone b2:8d:6c:9f:dd:00 -49  1       Y  US WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                   NETGEAR25 a0:04:60:1a:5a:87 -62  9       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                   CBCI-4F58 60:3d:26:57:4f:5c -86  6       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
```

What's going on and how can I fix this?  Thanks in advance.

(The Github issue is at https://github.com/keithrbennett/wifiwand/issues/20.)

This HP related error is confirmed at https://clburlison.com/macos-wifi-scanning/, which says:

When you run airport with the --xml flag the command would fail to output properly formatted xml data...one idea is that HP printers are broadcasting a SSID with unsafe characters...

[which is close, but it is the model name, not the SSID, that seems to generate the error]

Comment: @Buscar웃 ??? Do you mean SSID?

Comment: I have so far seen 3 outputs of the error condition, and they all share this in common: 1) Output always ends after printing the value for IE_KEY_WPS_MODEL_NAME, and 2) they are all HP printers. (I've seen output for this field for non-HP printers that does not cause this error.

Comment: Have you tried something like `airport -s -x | cat -v` to see if there are any special characters being sent to the output?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't understand what you are trying to say in your first comment. The BSSID has no spaces, but what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @TJLuoma I ran the command and redirected output to a file. The last line was `<string>HP LaserJet MFP M426fdw` and there were no characters, special or otherwise, after the `w`. (`od -x` on the file produced this as the last line: `0073600      4d20    5046    4d20    3234    6636    7764`).

Comment: I think @Buscar's point is that you could try to match the BSSID, and (presumably) from there to the end of the line. If you matched and removed that, it would leave you with the SSID as the remainder.

Comment: Note: truncated output somehow related to HP printers is still an issue even today on macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of the idea of trying to match the BSSID and removing that to the end of the line, I came up with this:

```
airport -s \
| sed 's# ..:..:..:..:..:.. .*##g ; s#^ *##g ; 1,1d' \
| sort -u
```

The `sed` line is actually 3 part:

1. Match the BSSID by looking for 2 characters separated by colons, repeated 5 times, and then everything to the end of the line (`.*`)
2. Match from the beginning of the line (`^`) and then any number of spaces (`.*`)
3. Deleted the first line (`1,1d`) which has the header information we don't care about: "SSID BSSID RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)"

The `sort -u` line makes sure each SSID only shows up once.

Maybe it's not ideal, but it might be an option.

The only possible "gotcha" I can think of is that I think sometimes BSSIDs can be reduced to 1 character instead of 2 if the first character is a zero, but I'm not sure if `airport` does that, and none of the networks I have access to include a zero in them, so I can't test for it. Maybe someone who is better at regexes can suggest a better one that what I have.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve here. I was able to use `airport -s` (without the `-x`) to get the network names (I am doing the parsing in Ruby so I have a ton of flexibility), but with the names right justified (left padded) there was no way to differentiate leading spaces that were part of the name and leading spaces that were there just for formatting. Sorry, I was not clear about that in my question.

Comment: You're quite right, I cannot imagine why anyone would put spaces at the front of their SSID name. I thought you were just worried about spaces _within_ the SSID name.

Comment: It surprised me too, but in my travels I've found several SSID's with a leading space, and even 1 with 3 leading spaces! And, yes, sorry, in my original message (which I have since edited to clarify) I did not make it clear that I was referring to leading spaces.

Comment: That's bizarre, but nothing should surprise me anymore. Good luck, I hope you find an answer

Comment: I think they put the leading spaces in the network name to appear at the top of a sorted list of available networks. Sneaky.

Answer (score 0):

2023 and it `airport -x` is still truncated :(

The textual output has a header though - and you can use it to your advantage. Use the first header row to find the spans of each column, then parse the next lines accordingly.

Python example - I use this to find collisions around me so I'll have my wifi router use an unoccupied channel:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from subprocess import getstatusoutput


cmd = "airport -s"
status, output = getstatusoutput(cmd)
assert status == 0
header = output.splitlines()[0]

C = re.compile(r"([A-Z]+)")
indices = [[m.group().strip(), m.start(), m.end()] for m in C.finditer(header)]
for i in range(len(indices) - 1):
    indices[i][2] = indices[i + 1][1]
    
indices[0][1] = 0
indices[-1][-1] = None

collisions = defaultdict(set)
data = []
for line in output.splitlines()[1:]:
    datum = {}
    for key, a, b in indices:
        value = line[a:b].strip()
        datum[key] = value
    
    collisions[datum["CHANNEL"]].add(datum["SSID"])
    data.append(datum)


import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: Knowing the column width does not help in the case of leading spaces though. If the names are right justified there is no way to know if a space is there to accomplish the right justification formatting, or if it is part of the name. Am I missing something?